# ¿Como puedo documentar un poco mis funciones creadas en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, formato, documentacion

Estoy tratando de buscar una manera de documentar un poco mis funciones, es decir, utilizo VS Code y cuando usas una función nativa de Python (y tienes el paquete de Python instalado) y colocas el cursor sobre la función, aparece una pequeña ventana que explica brevemente que hace la funciones y describe un poco los parámetros, me gustaría poder conseguir ese mismo efectos con funciones que yo pueda creas (Si es que es posible).

El formato realmente no me importa, en algunos editores veo que la misma ventana la muestran con un formato diferente, incluso colocan cuadro y demás. Realmente el formato no me importa mucho, aun que si también pudiera modificar el formato seria excelente, solo necesito poder documentar las funciones, si alguien podría ayudarme estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Sería mejor si pudieras mostrar algún ejemplo de lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En Python la forma más simple de documentar el código es mediante [`docstrings`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-docstring). Simplemente abre comillas luego de la función y escribe su descripción. No importa cuáles comillas, solo deben ser las mismas de apertura que de cierre. Así:

```
def suma(a, b):
    "Suma dos números."

    return a + b
```

Pero si quieres que la documentación sea de varias líneas debes usar 3 comillas para abrir y cerrar. Por ejemplo:

```
def suma(a, b):
    """
    Suma dos números.
    int o float
    """

    return a + b
```

---

Algo que ayudará a la hora de programar es indicar el tipo que la función espera que tenga cada parámetro.

Puedes hacerlo escribiendo dos puntos y el tipo que debería recibir luego del nombre del parámetro. Así:

```
def suma(a: int, b: int):
    "Suma dos números."

    return a + b
```

También puedes indicar el tipo que la función puede devolver si agregas `->` luego de los parámetros y el tipo en cuestión. Por ejemplo:

```
def suma(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    "Suma dos números."

    return a + b
```

Puedes ver que es bastante limitado. Por eso existen tipos especiales:

- [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any), literalmente cualquier tipo es válido.
- [`NoReturn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NoReturn), al contrario que `Any`, indica que la función no devuelve ningún valor. Solo puede ser usado para indicar el tipo de retorno.
- [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional), significa que puede ser o no del tipo especificado. Por ejemplo: `Optional[int]`.
- [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union), te permite combinar tipos enumerándolos separados por coma y entre corchetes. Supón que ahora quieres que la función `suma` acepte parámetros y pueda devolver un valor de tipo `float` también. Lo harías así:

  ```
  def suma(a: Union[int, float], b: Union[int, float]) -> Union[int, float]:
      "Suma dos números."

      return a + b
  ```
- [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable), espera una función. Se usa de forma similar a `Union`. Entre corchetes recibe una lista de los tipos de los parámetros y el tipo de retorno. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  def ordenar(comparador: Callable[[int, int], bool], lista: List) -> List:
      "Ordena una lista de números."

      listaOrdenada = lista
      for i in range(0, len(lista)):
          menor = i

          # Encuentra el mayor número entre la posición i + 1
          # y el final de la lista y lo coloca en la posición i.
          for j in range(i + 1, len(lista)):
              if comparador(lista[j], lista[menor]):
                  menor = j

          listaOrdenada[i], listaOrdenada[menor] = listaOrdenada[menor], listaOrdenada[i]

      return listaOrdenada

  ordenado = ordenar(lambda a, b: a < b, [2, 5, 1, 8])
  ```

Hay más tipos especiales. Todos se encuentran en el módulo [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Así que no olvides importarlos antes de usarlos.

Comment: No responde a la pregunta "me gustaría poder conseguir ese mismo efectos con funciones que yo pueda creas"

Comment: @CandidMoe Creo que **si** responde a la pregunta. Cuando el OP dice `con funciones que yo pueda creas`, se refiere a documentar sus propias funciones, las escritas por él mismo.

Comment: @Trauma Yo entendí eso.

Comment: @Trauma. Como respuesta es deficiente, pues no explica nada  sobre los docstring y manda al OP a mirar documentación a otro sitio. Es un puro enlace realmente.

Comment: @CandidMoe Bueno, con eso me desarmas, no puedo discutirlo.

Comment: @CandidMoe me parece que no hay mucho que responder. Si tienes una mejor respuesta puedes publicarla.

Comment: ¿Que son esos "Union"? ¿Que efectos tienen en el código? ¿Qué otras cosas puedo escribir en lugar de "Union"? ¿Donde documento el tipo y uso de los parámetros? ¿Debo usar triple comilla doble o puedo usar comilla simple? ¿En qué linea empiezan las comillas?

Comment: @Mateo Realmente me ayudo tu respuesta muchísimo, y eso era lo que quería, si bien es cierto los demás términos que colocaste en los argumento no entiendo que son, leeré la información que me enviaste para comprenderlos, pero conseguí lo que buscaba. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: @WalterPH espero que ahora entiendas mejor la respuesta.